# Play 2 sound files by JS one after another

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, html5-audio

I am trying to build a script(Greasemonkey) that will play five.mp3 at first and then after ending six.mp3
I'm using this code below but both the files are playing simultaneously
please give a solution for this

```
 var count = document.createElement('audio');
 count.src = "https://example.com/five.mp3";
 count.preload = 'auto';
 count.play();

 var x = document.createElement('audio');
 x.src = "https://example.com/six.mp3";
 x.preload = 'auto';
 x.play();
```

Comment: Start by having a look at MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio. You specifically want to look at the `ended` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

Comment: But why this is tagged "javascript' ?

Comment: `new` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript.

Comment: Do you need a javascript to do you job?

Comment: Anything which i can use as a greasemonkey script will work

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example to show how to do your job in javascript:

```
var count = document.createElement('audio');
count.src = "https://example.com/five.mp3";
count.preload = 'auto';
count.play();
count.onended=playSix;

function playSix()
{
  var x = document.createElement('audio');
  x.src = "https://example.com/six.mp3";
  x.preload = 'auto';
  x.play();
}
```